# Resizing Canvas Elements with Mouse Events with EaselJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, easeljs

I'm trying to draw elements to a canvas and then allow the user to resize them by clicking and dragging them.  I've implemented this with Kinetic JS library, but my development team is moving over to Easel JS.

[Here is the code with the Kinetic library.](http://pastebin.com/aCRvNcmd)

This works well enough.

I get about this far in Easel JS, but this code doesn't do anything.  The canvas is totally blank.  I realize that I'm not sure how to:

- call mouse events -- here I'm trying to attach them to the DOM element, as in [this tutorial](http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2011/01/25/layering-multiple-canvas-elements-using-javascript-and-easeljs/)

  where to set the resize function -- separate function?  called within the tick() function?

  grab the mouse coordinates

```
    var canvas;
var stage;
var rect;

var mousePos = new Point(); 
var update = true;

var rectX = 10;
var rectY = 10;
var rectW = 100;
var rectH = 50;
var rectXOffset = 50;
var rectYOffset = 50;

var newWidth;
var newHeight;

function init() {
    // create stage and point it to the canvas:
    canvas = document.getElementById("testCanvas");
    stage = new Stage(canvas);

    // overlay canvas used to draw target and line
    canvasWrapper = $("#testCanvas");

    // listen for a mouse down event
    canvasWrapper.mousedown(onMouseDown);

    // listen for mouse up event
    canvasWrapper.mouseup(onMouseUp);

    // enable touch interactions if supported on the current device:
    if (Touch.isSupported()) { Touch.enable(stage); }

    // enabled mouse over / out events
    stage.enableMouseOver(10);

    // start drawing instructions
    var rect = new Shape();
    rect.graphics
        .setStrokeStyle(1)
        .beginStroke(Graphics.getRGB(25,25,112,.7))
        .drawRect(rectX,rectY,rectW,rectH);

    // add rectangle to stage
    stage.addChild(rect);

    // render stage
    stage.update();

    // set the tick interval to 24 fps
    Tick.setInterval(1000/24);

    // listen for tick event
    Tick.addListener(window, true);

    // pause
    Tick.setPaused(false);

}

//called when user clicks on canvas
function onMouseDown(e) {

    mousePos.x = e.stageX;
    mousePos.y = e.stageY

    // check to see if mouse is within offset of rectangle
    if(mousePos.x <= (rectW + rectXOffset) || mousePos.y <= (rectH + rectYOffset)) {
        // set update to true
        update = true;

        // unpause tick
        Tick.setPaused(false);

    }

}

function onMouseUp(e) {
    update = false;
    Tick.setPaused(true);
}

function tick() {
    // this set makes it so the stage only re-renders when an event handler indicates a change has happened.
    if (update) {
       if(mousePos.x - rectX < 50) 
       {
        newWidth = 50;
       } else {
        newWidth = mousePos.x - rectX;
       }
       if(mousePos.y - rectY < 50) 
       {
        newHeight = 50;
       } else {
        newHeight = mousePos.y -rectY;
       }
        rectW = newWidth;
        rectH = newHeight;

        rect.clear();

        rect.graphics
        .setStrokeStyle(1)
        .beginStroke(Graphics.getRGB(65,65,65,.7))
        .drawRect(0,0,rectW,rectH);

        // add rectangle to stage
        stage.addChild(rect);

        update = false; // only update once
        stage.update();
    }
}
```

I know it shouldn't be this difficult and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you looked at [fabric.js](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/) Moving and resizing objects is built-in so it should be trivial to implement what you're describing. Take a look at [kitchensink demo](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/kitchensink/).

Comment: Also, which elements are you drawing on canvas? With fabric you can draw simple shapes, as well as images and even complex shapes from SVG (not all SVG can be parsed successfully but simple shapes work well).

Comment: The link above for fabric is outdated.  [This is the new location](http://fabricjs.com/).

Comment: You ever figure this out? Was easy with fabric but I can't figure it out with Easel